# mysqli update where item id is equal to last eight if item id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, varchar

Sorry if this has been asked before! Here is what im trying to do.

I need to update column "other" WHERE $lasteight is equal to the last eight characters of the item id

**for example** 
I have item 8542658s5s4a2158 in my db

**I need to do**
$lasteight="5s4a2158";
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE inv SET other='log_itm' WHERE item_id='$lasteight'");

Again sorry if this has been asked before I have been searching for hours!!
Thanks a million!

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my self well enough. I will be using $_POST to pass the last eight of the item id to MYSQLI update script I will not know what the full item id is just the last eight.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lasteight = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lasteight']);

mysqli_query($con, "
    UPDATE inv SET
        other = 'log_itm'
    WHERE
        RIGHT(item_id, 8) = '$lasteight'
");

// OR

mysqli_query($con, "
    UPDATE inv SET other = 'log_itm' WHERE item_id LIKE '%". $lasteight ."'
");
```

Comment: giving this a try now!